# Image with text created in IrfanView is blurry in video editor

Tags: windows-7

I have some images in HEIC format on iPhone. I took them to IrfanView, added text and saved it. When I used these images in a video editor (to create a video/ slideshow) the images are blurry and not clearly readable. The images are created at 600DPI. Most of the images are photos of places with description.

Comment: >> "The images are created at 600 dpi."  DPI is not a meaningful measure of resolution.  What is the resolution of the images *in pixels*?  What format did you save them in from IrfanView and with what compression settings?  What resolution is the video saved to from the video editor?

Answer (score 1):

HEIC files can contain both high resolution images [*and* low-resolution thumbnails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format#Features). Most likely, you edited the thumbnail, not the high-quality image.

Look in the HEIC file for the best-quality image, and edit that.